# Can I not mix @NonNullByDefault with inherited classes that have no null annotation constraint?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, nullable

I'm experimenting with [Eclipse null annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_annotations.htm) and I'm getting an error. I have a class A (example below) of which I do not have the source. I want to extend it for a class which is annotated by `@NonNullByDefault`. This throws an error because the `@NonNull` constraint does not match the unconstrained (nullable as inherited) parameters of the parent class.

Eclipse recommends adding `@Nullable` but this does not make the error go away.

Am I doing something wrong?

Class A:

```
public class A {
   public void SomeMethod(
      String[] a)
   {

   }
}
```

Class B:

```
@NonNullByDefault
public class B extends A {
   @Override
   public void SomeMethod(
      @Nullable String[] a)
   {

   }
}
```

The error I receive is:

> Illegal redefinition of parameter a, inherited method from A does not
>   constrain this parameter

Comment: Duplicate of https://bugs.eclipse.org/513209, which is in need of an answer before we can decide whether it's a bug or works as designed.

Comment: I wrote the question here before deciding that I thought it to be bug. It turns out it's a bug with Eclipse's QuickFix feature placing the `@Nullable` in the wrong location. I'm going to write up a proper answer to this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `@NonNullByDefault` with inherited, unconstrained classes, but an explicit `@Nullable` constraint must be applied to method parameters of any method which is overriden. This is because the default, unconstrained behavior for java, is to allow nulls.

The confusion here is a result of a misplacement of the `@Nullable` annotation. The placement in the original question suggests that the array *contents* should not be null rather than the array itself.

There is a bug but it's not with the annotation; it's a result of Eclipse (as of 4.6) placing the annotation in the wrong location with the Quick Fix feature, reinforcing an erroneous placement which does not correct the error.

The correct placement for arrays is:

```
public void SomeMethod(
   String @Nullable[] a)
{

}
```